# Robot framework can I reuse test cases with multiple interfaces

Tags: web, command-line-interface, robotframework

I have a lot of high level test cases.
I have the same keywords implemented for:
CLI (telnet)
WEB

Is there an easy way to run those test cases by not duplicating files, just passing a command line argument or something similar - to run these test cases for both CLI and WEB?

Comment: can you provide an example of your problem to understand it better.

Comment: In theory it's possible, with a framework architecture having high level abstractions (a keyword `Execute the operation` that's not tightly coupled with the implementation steps, but calls such keywords based on ->) and branching logic (`if $env == 'cli' run_keyword('cli_implementation') else run_keyword('web_implementation')`), but it very much depends on what you have already as structure, what your goal is, and mostly - what level of complexity you can tolerate in your framework. Thus backing-up Pankaj Mishra's comment - show samples of your code, and elaborate further.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved in different ways and much depends on how you want to structure your test case base and scripts.

1. **Start application**. If you have specific resource files for your Web and CLI keywords with the same keyword names for the same checks/processing then remove the unwanted files before you start Robot.
2. **Custom Import Keyword** In addition to importing a resource file in the [Settings section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files) you can also import a resource file through a keyword: [Import Resource](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Resource). This has the added advantage that you can use variables to create the file reference. For example if you have a global with Web/CLI and seperated the files using a directory, then this can be the folder name reference.
3. **Test Case Tagging** By duplicating your test cases you can load all the keywords for CLI and Web. Their keywords should be unique, otherwise they will conflict. By adding [Test Case tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases) you can utilize the tag filter feature when starting Robot to run only those test cases that have and/or lack certain tags.

Given that your test cases are unique test cases in the sense that they test different UI's I'd be enclined to seperate at test case level and use tags. Though there isn't a right or wrong way if you make a conscious decision.

As this closely relates to a solution maintaining settings for different environments, please keep that in mind as well.